# Работа переменной Random

Tags: c#

Есть массив который заполняется образцами данного класса :

```
protected class Neuron  // Класс обозначающий нейрон
        {
            double[] Weights;  // Веса всех входов

            Random r = new Random();
            public Neuron(int InputCount)
            {
                Weights = new double[InputCount];  // Создание масива весов
                for (int w = 0; w < InputCount; w++)  // Заполнение весов случайными значениями
                    Weights[w] = r.NextDouble();
            }
```

Но почему-то у всех нейронов в данном массиве массив Weights одинаковый, можете объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: Если создавать экземпляры Random в одно и тоже время (например в цикле), то они выдают одинаковые последовательности. Создавайте `new Random` только один раз.

Comment: Random без параметров инициалируется по системным часам, у них не очень большое разрешение, поэтому если быстро создавать экземпляры Random в одно время, они все будут инициализированы одинаковым сидом. Видимо, это и происходит.

Comment: @Zergatul да помогло, спасибо. оформите в виде ответа, отмечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Random` в .NET инициалируется по системному времени (если создавать без параметра `seed`). В таком случае если создавать экземпляры `Random` достаточно быстро друг за другом, они инициализируются одним значением и генерируют одну последовательность. Что бы избежать этого создавайте только один экземпляр `Random`.

От @Андрей NOP: Вышесказанное актуально только для .NET Framework, и неактуально для .NET Core.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что для .NET Core это уже неактуально

Comment: @АндрейNOP а там что для инициализации используется?

Comment: @MiT, другой статический Random, генерирующий случайные начальные зерна. Подробнее можете просмотреть в исходниках

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, добавил